# How does C handle EOF?

Tags: c, feof

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* f=fopen("book2.txt","r");
    char a[200];
    while(!feof(f))
    {
        fscanf(f,"%s",a);
        printf("%s ",a);
        printf("%d\n",ftell(f));
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

I have the code above. book2.txt contains "abcdef abcdef" with the cursor move to a newline(ie:abcdef abcdef\n). I get the results below.

```
abcdef 6
abcdef 13
abcdef 19
```

I expect to get

```
abcdef 6
abcdef 13
15
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `feof` probably doesn't work like you think it does.

Comment: See [`while (!foef(fp))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Answer (score 4):

Test the I/O operations themselves; don't use `feof()` unless you're writing Pascal (and C is not Pascal!)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f = fopen("book2.txt", "r");
    char a[200];
    if (f != 0)
    {
        while (fscanf(f, "%199s", a) == 1)
        {
            printf("%s ", a);
            printf("%ld\n", ftell(f));
        }
        putchar('\n');
        fclose(f);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the revised code tests `f` before using it, and protects against buffer overflow by specifying how long the string is in the conversion specification.  Be aware that `%s` reads up to a white space character; it does not read lines unless there is no white space on each line.

You use `feof()` to distinguish between a conversion failure, an I/O error and EOF after an operation such as `fscanf()` reports trouble.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f = fopen("book2.txt", "r");
    char a[200];
    if (f != 0)
    {
        while (fscanf(f, "%199s", a) == 1)
        {
            printf("%s ",a);
            printf("%ld\n", ftell(f));
        }
        putchar('\n');
        if (feof(f))
            printf("EOF\n");
        else if (ferror(f))
            printf("I/O error\n");
        else
            printf("Conversion failed\n");
        fclose(f);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With `%s`, you won't get to conversion failed, and I/O error is pretty improbable too.  If the conversion specifier was `%d`, though, a punctuation character in the data could land you with 'Conversion failed'.

In over 25 years worth of C coding, I've got 2 places in my code that use `feof()` out of thousands of files (I did a [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13113285/15168) a few months ago), and in both cases, the code is distinguishing between EOF and error (roughly as shown).

Comment: Your format specifier for the ftell() argument is wrong. `ftell()` returns a `long`, not an `int`.

Comment: @Wiz: true; I copied from the question and wasn't scrutinizing the content of the line.  I'll fix; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`feof` will not tell you that you've hit the end of the file until *after you've **hit*** the end of the file. Check the result (return value) from `fscanf`. It will tell you when it cannot read any more. If `fscanf` hits the end of file, *it* will return EOF (and `feof` will return true after this has happened).

Now just for fun, take a look at this way of doing it. Don't actually ever do it this way.

```
while(1) {
    switch(fscanf(f,"%s",a)){
        case 1: 
            printf("%s ",a);
            printf("%d\n",ftell(f));
            continue;
        case EOF:
            break;
    }
    break;
}
```

This way is wrong because it is *clever*. With a few more cases, the behavior of the loop as a whole would become very difficult to discern (eg. [this program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8734/2381)).  With `fscanf` you really only need to know if you got all the data you need to continue, or not. Let the next input reading function deal with EOF when it finds it. *This* call to `fscanf` needs to fill *x* number of values so,

```
if (fscanf(f,"%d %d %d", &i, &j, &k) != 3)
    /* cannot continue. need i j k values for next computation */
```

then do your error-response, or exit the loop, or whatever your program needs to do next. But if `fscanf` returns anything other than 3, it did not read 3 values.

Comment: Please explain to us what's wrong with *this way*, so that we know what to do differently, and you have my vote.

Comment: Ok. I tried. I think I matured a little while writing that. :)

Comment: The WTF there is a loop that only loops once, which isn't relevant to this question. Consider `int foo; for (foo = fscanf(stdin, "%s", bar); foo == 1; foo = fscanf(stdin, "%s", bar)) { printf("%s\n", bar); }`... After this loop, one can check the value returned to see if it was a match failure (which can't happen for this format string) or a read failure that lead to fscanf returning something other than 1.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying here. The WTF *where?*

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is: Aim to teach people how to do things the correct way, rather than teaching people what the incorrect way is. "The WTF" is a reference to a website named "the daily WTF".

Comment: Agreed. But it seemed Jonathan Leffler already had that covered. All that was left was *something interesting to think about.*

Comment: @modifiablelvalue This is actually a step forward for me. Not too long ago, I would have called the same code *good.*